# How to filter embedded array in mongo document with morphia

Tags: arrays, mongodb, morphia

Given my Profile data looks like below, I want to find the profile for combination of userName and productId
 and only return the profile with the respective contract for this product.

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "userName": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "language": "NL",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
    "contracts": [
        {
            "contractId": "DEMO1-CONTRACT",
            "productId": "ticket-api",
            "startDate": ISODate('2016-06-29T09:06:42.391Z'),
            "roles": [
                {
                    "name": "Manager",
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "activity": "ticket",
                            "permission": "createTicket"
                        },
                        {
                            "activity": "ticket",
                            "permission": "updateTicket"
                        },
                        {
                            "activity": "ticket",
                            "permission": "closeTicket"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "contractId": "DEMO2-CONTRACT",
            "productId": "comment-api",
            "startDate": ISODate('2016-06-29T10:27:45.899Z'),
            "roles": [
                {
                    "name": "Manager",
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "activity": "comment",
                            "permission": "createComment"
                        },
                        {
                            "activity": "comment",
                            "permission": "updateComment"
                        },
                        {
                            "activity": "comment",
                            "permission": "deleteComment"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I managed to find the solution how to do this from the command line. But I don't seem to find a way how to accomplish this with Morphia (latest version).

```
db.Profile.aggregate([
    { $match: {"userName": "john.doe@gmail.com"}},
    { $project: {
        contracts: {$filter: {
            input: '$contracts',
            as: 'contract',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$contract.productId', "ticket-api"]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

This is what I have so far.  Any help is most appreciated

```
Query<Profile> matchQuery = getDatastore().createQuery(Profile.class).field(Profile._userName).equal(userName);
getDatastore()
     .createAggregation(Profile.class)
     .match(matchQuery)
     .project(Projection.expression(??))
```

Note... meanwhile I found another solution which does not use an aggregation pipeline.

```
    public Optional<Profile> findByUserNameAndContractQuery(String userName, String productId) {
        DBObject contractQuery = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start(Contract._productId, productId).get();
        Query<Profile> query =
                getDatastore()
                        .createQuery(Profile.class)
                        .field(Profile._userName).equal(userName)
                        .filter(Profile._contracts + " elem", contractQuery)
                        .retrievedFields(true, Profile._contracts + ".$");
        return Optional.ofNullable(query.get());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the best way (under assumption I only want to return max. 1 element from array) to filter embedded array.

```
db.Profile.aggregate([
   { $match: {"userName": "john.doe@gmail.com"}},
   { $unwind: "$contracts"},
   { $match: {"contracts.productId": "comment-api"}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

To match according to your first design you could try the projection settings with morphia aggregation pipeline.

```
Query<Profile> matchQuery = getDatastore().createQuery(Profile.class).field(Profile._userName).equal(userName);

getDatastore()
 .createAggregation(Profile.class)
 .match(matchQuery)
 .project(Projection.expression("$filter", new BasicDBObject()
      .append("input", "$contracts")
      .append("as", "contract")
      .append("cond", new BasicDBObject()
          .append("$eq", Arrays.asList('$$contract.productId', "ticket-api")));
```

Also see the example written by the morphia crew around line 88 at https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationTest.java.